# android indexoutofboundsexception passing bundle through intent

Tags: java, android

I have stumbled upon an issue I can't figure out right now. I get an index out of bounds exception when I pass a bundle to a new activity in intent extras.

I use the following code:

```
Intent intent = new intent(this, statelistactivity.class);

Bundle bundle = new bundle();
Bundle.putInt("id", _id);
Bundle.putString("name", _name);
Intent.putExtras(bundle);

startactivity(intent);
```

In the receiving activity I use:

```
String name = getIntent().getString("name);
```

Following the same principle for the int.

However my code never gets here because of an `outofboundsexception`. What could cause this?

Comment: Post your LogCat output.

Comment: As i know, outofbounds exception normaly rises when there is an array or a list and you are trying to access an iten, which is not in the range of this array

Comment: I don't think this code even compiles

Comment: It doesnt. Thats why im posting here. To make it compile again.. and year. U arw right mocialov. But specifkcally between thesw 2 intents i can guarantee not a single array is involved. In others. There are

Comment: The above code can't have IndexOutOfBounds anywhere. Please post related info to your question! More part of code where error occurs, stack trace while running error, error output while compiling...whatever thing/clue will help.

Comment: Its been reaolved. I cannt mark as answered until 2 days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself. It was completely diferent from what i suspected.

I have a loop running somewhere for a completely different part of the app. But in the program. The error resided there. Deep down the source, it was in fact an arraylist causing it. Thanks for your time and replies.

Answer (score 0):

You are not trying to get your string from bundle in which you have put your strings.
You should try getting first bundle and from that bundle get all variables-

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
String name = b.getString("name");
```

Comment: Thanks :) it doesnt solve it however. I am sjspecting the error has a deeper source